# jQuery ajax not firing in child function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I'm making a script that is pretty large so I'm taking a object oriented javascript approach.
When trying to use jQuery's ajax (or before this the shorthand for document ready) It doesn't get fired and I have no clue why.

(copy-pasting the whole document ready code into the chrome console shows that the ajax call does work, but it just doensn't run inside the child function)

My code:

```
// Main class
function Arina(loginstate) {
    var loginstate = loginstate;
}


/**
 * attempts to log the user in
 * @
 * @param  {string} username [user's username]
 * @param  {string} password [user's password]
 * @return {array}           [status, message]      
 */
Arina.prototype.login = function(username, password) {
    /**
     * Validate if the user has filled in all required fields
     */
    if (username == '' || username == null)  return [false, 'No username given.']; 
    if (password == '' || password == null)  return [false, 'No password given.'];

    /**
     * Set up ajax payload
     */
    var payload = {
        username : username,
        password : password,
        unhashed  : true
    }


    /**
     * Document ready for jQuery
     */
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        /**
         * Make ajax call to check credentials
         * @param {object} 'payload' [Form data]
         */
        $.ajax({
            url     : '/arina/app',
            type    : 'POST',
            data    : payload
        }).always(function(response, status, xhr){
            if (response == 'success') {
                return [true, 'Login successful.'];
            } else {
                return [response, status, xhr];
            }

            console.log("I'm not getting fired!!"); // Code ever reaches this.
        });



        /**
         * Catch jQuery ajax error
         * @param  {object} event       
         * @param  {object} xhr         
         * @param  {object} settings    
         * @param  {string} thrownError 
         * @return {array}             
         */
        $(document).ajaxError(function(event, xhr, settings, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.status == 401) return [false, 'Invalid username or password.'];
            if (xhr.status == 500) return [false, 'Internal server error, please contact an administrator.'];
        });
    });
}

// I call the method once the script has been loaded (along with the rest of the JS files)
var arina = new Arina(1);
arina.login('test', 'test');
```

### Update

The child function DOES fire the ajax, but never calls the callback function.

Comment: When do you call `Arina.prototype.login()`?

Comment: @Barmar I call the function like so: var arina = new Arina(1); arina.login('test', 'test')

Comment: It's usually not necessary to call `$(document).ready()` inside functions, if the function won't be called until after the page is loaded.

Comment: Why do you expect that to call `login()`?

Comment: Check the Network tab of the console to see if you're getting an error when calling AJAX.

Comment: You're calling `arina.login()` with no arguments, so the `if` statement at the beginning will make it return `[false, 'No username given.']`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, forgot to add that in the code. I found out the ajax gets called but I never get a callback function thus resulting in nothing happening.

Comment: It sounds like the AJAX server script is failing. There should be an error code in the Network tab.

Comment: @Barmar Aparrently it was a stupid logic error or mine, I can't return a value asynchronously. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log("I'm not getting fired!!");` is not reached because the return statements above it.

here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cauu6dmw/)

two major changes:

- callback function of `$.ajax` is corrected
- `$(document).ready` is removed

Additional info:
instead of:

```
    $.ajax({
        url     : '/arina/app',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : payload
    })
```

you could use:

```
    $.post('/arina/app', data)
```

instead of `always` with a check on the result you could use:

```
    .done(function() {
        // handle success
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // handle fail
    })
```